# How to add exchange snapin using iron python

Tags: python, powershell, ironpython, exchange-server, powershell-2.0

Below is my Iron Python script it works fine with all the system level commands (get-process etc) but I want to add MS-Exchange  snap-in to invoke exchange command. Can some one help me ?

def RunScript(script):

```
runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()
runspace.Open()
pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline()
cache = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()
pipeline.Commands.AddScript(script)

pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String")
results = pipeline.Invoke()
pickled = []
for thing in results:
    pickled.append(thing.ToString())
return pickled
```

Thanks
Susant

Answer (score 0):

You can add a call to `Add-PSSnapin` in 'script' before you pass it to the AddScript method.
You can also add with this:

```
ps = PowerShell.Create()
ps.AddCommand("Add-PSSnapin").AddParameter("Name","Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin")
```

Comment: it is powershell command "Add-PSSnapin". How do I do in Iron Python? What is the equivalent function available ? to add Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin into runspace

Comment: 'script' is powershell code too, right? So you could add a call to add Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin at the top of it.

Comment: Updated my answer with another option.